# mySQL circular query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables say **table 1: Member** and **table 2: Info**. ID is primary key and A & B are primary keys in second table.
A represents introduced from and B represents someone who introduces. So the entry 002 -> 001 means that 001 introduces 002.

I want to have a query to show those Name in which 001 is not involved, meaning that those people who 001 introduces AND those people who introduce 001 are NOT involved.

[image]

[image]

This is what i have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Info.A
FROM Info
WHERE NOT (A="001" OR B="001")

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT Info.B
FROM Info
WHERE NOT (A="001" OR B="001)
```

The expected result should be `004` but my query is also including `003`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the ids where `001` is involved, then the result is **NOT IN** those ids.

```
SELECT * FROM Member
WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT IF(A = '001', B, A) 
  FROM Info WHERE A = '001' OR B = '001'
  UNION
  SELECT '001'
)
```

**[THE SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59fb3/1)**.